# Access 2013 - Updating a Table using a calculated field in a Form

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

I have a Table called `Records` with the following four columns:

`ID | StartChainage | EndChainage | DistanceTraveled`

The `DistanceTraveled` is the difference between `EndChainage` and `StartChainage`. For each new record, the `StartChainage` should be equal to the `EndChainage` of the previous one.

I have created a Form called `Record1` where I can only add values in the field called `EndChainage`, while in the field `StartChainage` I use the following expression:

```
=IIf([ID]=1,0,DLookUp("[EndChainage]","Record","[ID]=Forms![Record1]![ID]-1"))
```

Where I actually say that for the first record in the Table "Records" (i.e. ID=1) the value in the `StartChainage` must be `0`, else it should obtain the value of the `EndChainage` field of the previous record.

This works fine and I have a Form with fields where I only input the value of the `EndChainage` and the Form sets the value of the `StartChainage` for the next record and it also calculates the `DistanceTraveled`.

The problem is that the calculated fields are NOT updating the relevant fields of the Table. In the Table the only updated fields are the `EndChainage` ones, *i.e. the ones I only type manually the values*.

How can I make the Table to get automatically updated by the calculated fields of the Form?

Maybe I could use calculated fields in the Table itself, but this is **not** what I really want.

Comment: Calculated controls are not supposed to update fields in tables. If you want to update a table based on a calculation, use an update query.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But in any case, how can I make Access to use the typed value in the field [EndChainage] of the previous record as the value of the field [StartChainage] of the new record?
As i explained, in the Form i can do this and it works fine. The problem is that after typing the value in the [EndChainage] of the previous record, the automatically updated [StartChainage] of the new record, even if it appears in the Form, is not stored in the corresponding field in the Table.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=IIf([ID]=1,0,DLookUp("[EndChainage]","Record","[ID]=" & Forms![Record1]![ID]-1 & ""))
```

Check if you get the ID:

```
=Forms![Record1]![ID]-1
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. Sadly it didn't work :)